# Tracing a bug in a "reverse domain" program in Java

Tags: java, dns, reverse

My code is supposed to reverse a domain. For example, if the input is www.google.com.uk, it should print uk.com.google.www

My problem is that my code prints uk.com..google.www

I can't figure where the extra . comes from or how to remove it. I did some tracing and found that www.stack.com.edu.uk would return uk.edu..com..stack.www

```
import java.util.*;

public class Domainreverse {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String domain = sc.nextLine();
        int x;
        int start = 0;
        String reversed_domain = "";
        boolean flag = false;


        do{

            x = domain.indexOf(".",start+1);
            if(x==-1){
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            reversed_domain = domain.substring(start,x+1) +reversed_domain;

            start = x;


        } while(flag==false);
        int length = domain.length();
        int z = domain.lastIndexOf(".");
        String enddomain = domain.substring(z+1,length);
        reversed_domain = enddomain+reversed_domain;
        int p = reversed_domain.lastIndexOf(".");
        reversed_domain = reversed_domain.substring(0,p);



        System.out.print(reversed_domain);



    }

}
```

Comment: if the intent of reversing the domain name is for sorting purposes, then don't.  Correct sorting of domain names require that they be sorted _by reverse label_, not on the entire string.

Comment: Why don't you just use `String.split()`?

Comment: I'm really new to programming, and this is an introductory course to Computer programming. I haven't been told this method, and it's my first time seeing it, but thanks I'll google, and see what it does.